# Pour copper area inside cutout Altium 19

Tags: pcb, altium

I have a board design in Altium 19 which has a differential pair on layer 2 and a power plane on layer 3 (the rest of L2 is GND).  I need to cut out the power plane on L3 and have an area of GND to give a reference for my diff pair - how can I acheive this in Altium?

I have tried making a cutout then drawing a copper pour within that, but the copper pour doesn't work, though the cutout does.  Also tried moving the polygons around in polygon manager, without success.[image: polygon cutout and area]

Comment: Breaking up the ground plane  is a bad idea, especially in the vicinity of a microcontroller. Why can't the traces be on L4 or even the power plane?

Comment: Having impedence controlled traces on inner layers is a bad idea. First the trace width/spacing changes dramatically and you lose your reference layer. I would figure out how to get this on the top or bottom layer, don't break up your ground plane.

Comment: Thanks both, your comments made me realise what I was trying to do was futile, thanks! controlled impedance tracks now routed on L1 with GND plane directly under.

Comment: @RonBeyer, I disagree with your claim that inner layer transmission lines are inherently bad. Stripline designs are entirely common. You can find numerous calculators to obtain the correct dimensions for your desired \$Z_0\$. It might be inconvenient to have to have two unbroken planes for reference instead of one, but it's also possible to use a power plane as a transmission line reference, if proper bypassing is used near the source and termination of the line.

Comment: @ThePhoton I agree that you *can* do it, but it requires a lot more care in using the power plane as a reference layer (as you said), and then on top of adding cuts in your ground plane makes this something you want to avoid on a 4-layer board if at all possible. Adding it there will probably require some very careful analysis to avoid problems not just with the traces in question, but the surrounding components, especially if something spans the break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you've found an alternative solution, but I'll still answer the question you asked in case it's useful for future readers.

> I have tried making a cutout then drawing a copper pour within that, but the copper pour doesn't work, though the cutout does.

You don't need to make a cut-out.

Just put the GND polygon inside the power polygon. Then, in the polygon manager, adjust the pour order so that the GND polygon is poured first. Then when the power polygon is poured, it will flow around the GND polygon, respecting your clearance rules as it pours.

It's also possible to just use the power plane as a reference for your transmission line. The main consideration is just to make sure there is good AC coupling (bypassing) between the power plane and ground planes, particularly near the two ends of your transmission lines.

Comment: thanks for that, I'll give that a go next time. Good info about using power planes as reference - I had only come across using ground before